# django: update database upon onsubmit dropdown

Tags: django

I am trying to create a ticketing system. What I want to do is when I change the Status dropdown list it should update the status of the ticket in the database. Also, I would like to update and view in the same page. Any insights if that would be possible?

forms.py

```
class ViewForm(forms.Form):
  statuses = [
    ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
    ('On Hold', 'On Hold'),
    ('Done', 'Done'),
    ('ForQA', 'ForQA'),
    ('QAPassed', 'QAPassed'),
    ('QARevs', 'QARevs'),
  ]
  status = forms.ChoiceField(label='Status', required=True, choices=statuses, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'actionform.submit();'}))
```

views.py

```
def view_sheet(request, project_id):
   project = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)
   tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project=project_id) 
   form = ViewForm()
   context = {
     'project': project,
     'tickets': tickets,
     'form': form,
   }
   return render(request, 'project/sheet/view.html', context)
```

view.html

```
<div class="tracker-sheet">
<div class="project-name">
  <h1>{{project.name}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <a href="{% url 'add_ticket' project.id %}">
    <button type="submit">New Ticket</button>
  </a>
</div >    
<div class="tracker-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Worked</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Status Date</th>
      <th>Received</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Agent</th>
      <th>Sub Type</th>
      <th>CID</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Task Description</th>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Info</th>
    </tr>
    {% for ticket in tickets %}
      <tr>
        <td><span class="table-constant"></span></td>            
        {% for field in form %}
        <td>{{field}}</td> <!-- Status dropdown list -->
        {% endfor %}
        <td><span class="table-constant">{{ticket.status_date}}</span></td>
        </form>
        <td><span class="table-constant">{{ticket.received}}</span></td>
        <td><span class="table-constant">{{ticket.due_date}}</span></td>
        <td><span class="table-constant"></span></td>
        <td><span class="table-constant">{{ticket.sub_type}}</span></td>
        <td><span class="table-vary"></span></td>
        <td><span class="table-constant">{{ticket.link}}</span></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="{{ticket.task_description}}"</td>
        <td><span class="table-constant"></span></td>
        <td><span class="table-constant">{{ticket.qty}}</span></td>
        <td></td>          
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

views.py

```
def update_status(request, ticket_id):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=ticket_id)
    status = request.GET.get(status)
    if status:
        ticket.status = status
        ticket.save()
    else:
        raise Http404
    return HttpResponse({'ticket_id': ticket.id, 'status': ticket.status, content_type='application/json')
```

And in the template (or remote js file):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".statuses").change(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "update_status/" + $(this).data("ticket_id) + "/?status=" $(this).val(), success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

urls.py:

```
....
url(r'^update_status/(?P<ticket_id>[\d]+)$', update_status),
....
```

NOTE: You'l need a different ticket id for each of these trs, so I'd add a `data-ticket_id = {{ ticket.id }}` to each `select`. That means your `{{ field }}` is going to have to get more declarative.

Something like:

```
<select id="status_{{ticket.id}}" class="statuses" data-ticket_id="{{ ticket.id }}" />
{% for k, v in statuses %}
    <option value="{{ k }}">{{ v }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a very well detailed and thorough answer.

Comment: Good example. Also, OP, you might want to check the user is logged in and has the proper rights to edit the content :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is totally possible.

**The idea:**
One way would be to use a javascript function call to update this field (AJAX GET or POST). This script will request a URL managed by the same view, or a new one.
The view would then process the request, return some data for you to parse and optionally confirm that the change what successful, or display an error.

**In practice:**
You can use for example a [jQuery Post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), with the URL parameter the one to your `view_sheet` (or like I said, a new view just for this purpose).
In your view you could play with [`request.is_ajax()`, a test on the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) that will be true when it comes from your jQuery post.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is when I change the Status dropdown list it should
>   update the status of the ticket in the database

Instead of this :

```
status = forms.ChoiceField(label='Status', required=True, choices=statuses, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'actionform.submit();'}))
```

Try this :

```
status = forms.ChoiceField(label='Status', required=True, choices=statuses, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onChange':'this.form.submit()'}))
```